# Django: AttributeError: 'MoneyField' object has no attribute 'related_model'

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-migrations

When I run the command: **python manage.py migrate** I got the error: **AttributeError: 'MoneyField' object has no attribute 'related_model'**.

[image]

I try to found something with **related_model** But I didn't find anything.

Is it possible to log any error when runs Django Migrations or get more details about the error?

Comment: Can you share your Models.py file? Its hard to deduce anything without looking at the models.

Comment: @kokeen, unfortunately, is about 12 new models I added to Django, if was only one, it will be easy =/

Comment: I have seen this error maybe a year ago when I was setting up models linked through foreign keys. Is MoneyField pointing to another model in foreign key relationship?

Comment: I am looking for it, but nothing until now, so weird.

Comment: @MichelAndrade can you share the models that are using the `MoneyField`?  I am almost certain the problem lies within one of those models.

Comment: @MichelAndrade: can you shar a single model where you use that `MoneyField`?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem https://www.codepile.net/pile/rn1jmgvM

Comment: @CalebGoodman https://www.codepile.net/pile/rn1jmgvM